# Cause a stack overflow with a while loop

Tags: c#

I'm trying to look into what causes exceptions to occur

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your name.");
string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
                while (playerName.Length == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Don't be a ****, enter a name!");
                }
```

This code compiles without causing a Stack Overflow exception.

I did something similar in a lecture which caused a stack overflow exception but this code does not. This means it cannot be adding to the stack. How would I write this code in such a way that it causes a stack overflow exception?

Comment: Where exactly do you think you are adding to the stack?

Comment: Because it doesn't put anything on to the stack? It just triggers the same method over and over again. Do not confuse this with recursion.

Comment: Your loop's body doesn't add any stack allocations, hence no stack overflow.

Comment: why do you think that an infinite loop must throw a stack overflow? also, there is no recursion in that code

Comment: How many times you see this message in output? Dont be a ****?

Comment: Oh ok, I was only asking because I did something very similar in a lecture and got a stack overflow and I can't see many differences (I'm still an apprentice and I haven't really looked at stacks much yet!

Comment: @SurjitSD it constantly repeats itself

Comment: @Pikoh yeah I don't know the difference so I just covered all bases. As I say I'm not very experienced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because simply running a loop does not add anything to the stack.

If it was an infinite recursive method you would get a `StackOverflowException`.
Why? because of the way the execution stack works - It stacks methods to be executed.
Suppose the following code:

```
public void A()
{
    B();
}

public void B()
{
    C();
}

public void C()
{
   // do some stuff.
}
```

Now, When you call method `A`, it executes `B`, leaving `A` in the execution stack. `B` executes `C`, leaving both `A` and `B` in the execution stack,
and when `C` completes and `B` completes, only then is `B` removed from the execution stack. In the same way, when `A` finally completes, it's removed from the execution stack.

Now that stack is very deep, so it's usually only overflowed with infinite recursions.

Since your call to `Console.WriteLine` is completed before your loop starts again, there is nothing left on the stack between iterations, and thus no stack overflow.

An easy way to cause a stackoverflow is by using recursion since recursive method calls will be stacked until the recursion comes to it's stopping condition and start returning values up the recursion chain. If that stopping condition is missing (an infinite recursion) or too far down the road, the stack will overflow.

From the [`StackOverflowException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?view=netframework-4.7.1) documentation page:

> StackOverflowException is thrown for execution stack overflow errors, typically in case of a very deep or unbounded recursion.

Comment: _" running a loop does not add anything to the stack"_ in this particular example yes, but not in general as you've stated.

Comment: The loop itself doesn't add anything to the stack. It's what you use inside it. But you are correct, of course - I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var playerName = "";
while ((playerName = Console.ReadLine())?.Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Don't be a ****, enter a name!");
}
```

Comment: This is how it should be asked but that's not the question. OP asks why he doesn't get an exception (and this won't help with that)

Comment: That's what confused me (and maybe I read the question wrong). I thought that the question was about how to fix it. Maybe my mistake :)